# What Starfleet ship classes are visible in the Season 1 finale of Star Trek: Picard?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-picard

In season 1, episode 10 of *Star Trek: Picard*, a fleet of Starfleet vessels arrive. What classes of vessels were present?

[image]

Comment: I was deeply unimpressed with the ending. It looked like they'd just copied and pasted the same ship design over and over again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only make out one class, and there are two nacelle variations visible for this type of ship. However, three classes *were* meant to be in *Star Trek: Picard*.

> According to Michael Chabon, the fleet was originally supposed to be more diverse: "There were three new classes of Starfleet ships approved for the climactic sequence. Whether all three can ultimately be seen or distinguished in the final screen version is unclear.
>
> - A heavy cruiser: the Inquiry-class. That's the Zheng He.
> - A carrier cruiser, similar to the Inquiry but with two distinctive forward 'prongs' or 'horns' off the elongated 'saucer': the Equity-class.
> - An explorer, with a distinctive 'open' or ring-style saucer: the Seeker-class."
>
> <sub>[Ex Astris Scientia, Starfleet Ship Classes A-K](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/starfleet_ships1.htm)</sub>

Comment: My edit placed everything into quote markdown, it’s how we denote what is a quote. Is there a reason you rolled it back?

Comment: No. Sorry, I'm just not sure how the markdown quote things work. How did you do it?

Comment: Add a `>` in front of the paragraph. You can always [edit] your post to view things if you're unsure. The [help page on formatting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) also gives some helpful tips.

Answer (score 3):

From [Space](https://www.space.com/star-trek-picard-episode-10-finale-recap.html) it looks similar to the Pathfinder Class from ST: Online. But one of the reasons the ships all look the same is that the VFX were finished the week before it was released giving the VFX team no time to vary the ship styles (VFX supervisor Ante Dekovic).

Internally, the USS *Zheng He* bridge is comprised of the bridge from *[ST: Discovery](https://blog.trekcore.com/2020/03/star-trek-picard-finale-review-et-in-arcadia-ego-part-2/)*

Conversely, [Den of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/star-trek-picard-finale-zheng-he-ship/) states that the *USS Zheng He* is similar to the *USS Ibn Mājid* which is a *Curiosity-Class* ship.

Michael Chabon, on [Instagram Talkbacks](https://www.instagram.com/michael.chabon/?hl=en), is a bit elusive saying that many of the *Curiosity-Class* ships were named after explorers (Zheng He was a 15C Chinese explorer and admiral), but then saying that the *Zheng He* was something new.

In the same [Den of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/star-trek-picard-finale-zheng-he-ship/) article, fans have said it looks like a composite of *Odyssey* and *Avenger* class from the online game.

Comment: I can see at least three starship variations in the onscreen footage of the fleet, so the VFX team had *some* time.  No idea what classes they are supposed to be tho.

Comment: @Moo Well, I was just going of what Ante Dekovic of the VFX team was quoted as saying. I wonder, maybe the variation is more about VFX and not class of ship...?

Comment: Trekyards went through frame by frame and even identified the old John Eaves design for STO circa early 2000's. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnLuc0llZo0

Two are just nacelle variations.

Comment: I'd say that STO Pathfinder Class is more like Intrepid Class.